# Programatically open folder and load and process files given path

Tags: matlab, path, directory

In my code I want the user to manually choose a folder of .wav files to process.

I used :

```
dname=uigetdir('C:'); 

%% dname gives the path to the folder directory and saves it as a variable
```

I know that you can use `cd directory name` and `cd ..` like in Linux with MATLAB, how do I detach the meaningful part of `dname` to be able to use the `cd` function?

For the looping through, I found a stackexchange answer that covered that.

```
files = dir('C:\myfolder\*.txt');
for k = 1:length(files)
    load(files(k).name, '-ascii')
end
```

Comment: Use function syntax instead of command syntax, i.e. `cd( dname )`. Or better still, don't change directory and load the full path, i.e. `load( fullfile( dname, files(k).name ) )`?

Comment: cd (dname ) worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dname=uigetdir('C:'); 

cd(dname); %make current directory, the directory specified by the path

files=dir('*.wav'); %get all the .wav files in the folder
for k=1:length(files); % loop through the files 1:last.wav 

    audio=cell(1, length(files)); %preallocate a cell with the appropriate size
    audio{k} = audioread(files(k).name); %input in the files

end   %files struct can be called after the end
```

[image: output]